# Cannot post to page as app

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

Facebooks documentation is inadecuate, confusing at best.

I have created an app, I have created a page for my business. I want to post updates on that page from my website as my App using the php-sdk.

I had this working perfectly with other pages/sites but nothing seems to be working any more.

I require offline_access, so I have followed the new endpoint as suggested in their docs.

Sequence of obtaining access_token with longer expiry:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={my_app_id}&redirect_uri=http://my_url.redirect/fb/fb_token.php&scope=publish_stream,offline_access,user_status,read_stream,email,user_groups,manage_pages&response_type=token
```

returned [TOKEN_1]

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={my_app_id}&client_secret={my_app_secret}&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=[TOKEN_1]
```

returned [ACCESS_TOKEN]

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]
```

returns list of my pages and apps and their relevant ids and access codes. This is where I got my final [DEFINITIVE_ACCESS_TOKEN] && [PAGE_ID]

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => {my_app_id},
    'secret' => {my_app_secret},
    'cookie' => false,
    'oauth'  => true
));

try {
    $attachment =  array(
        'access_token'  => [DEFINITIVE_ACCESS_TOKEN],
        'message'       => {my_message},
        'name'          => {my_title},
        'link'          => {my_url},
        'description'   => {my_description},
        'picture'       => {my_image_url},
     );
     $publishStream = $facebook->api('/[PAGE_ID]/feed', 'POST', $attachment);
 } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    die($e);
 }
```

This has returned an error message "OAuthException: (#200) Posts where the actor is a page cannot also include a target_id"

Where am I going wrong? Is there a tutorial of getting this to work perfectly anywhere or are we supposed to all be mind readers and guess how it is supposed to be done?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed you are using offline access

Offline access will no longer be available as of May 1, 2012.

See this
https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Make sure you have handling for this.

~K

Comment: As I stated, I am using the new endpoint as suggested in the offline_access_deprecated page.

I have found where the problem is however, I was passing the [PAGE_ID] as an int instead of a string (silly me). All is now working.